# Laravel Vue, Can't see images in production mode

Tags: laravel, vue.js

when i open the project in https mode, cant retrieve the images(receive 404 ).
Can someone help me?

Code:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <img src="/assets/photos/test.png"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
    name: "home"
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Are the images visible when in http mode? Can you access the images on individual url for eg: `https://myapp.com/public/assets/photos/test.png`

Answer (score 0):

v-bind src and require your photos

`<img :src="require('/assets/photos/test.png')"`

Comment: got the error " Cannot resolve directory 'require(''' "

Comment: did you bind the property with either `v-bind:src` or `:src`? or it's because you're not passing the absolute path. Use `@/assets/...` instead of `/assets/...`